# How to access "in progress word count" for Mac Microsoft Word 2008

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-word-2008

Word ordinarily counts the number of words in a document as you type, easily allowing you to keep track of how far you are into an assignment and bookmarking sections. A recent program update has removed this feature. I can still access word count by using the tools menu, however, this is not nearly as useful.  Any info would be appreciated.

My version saves in .docx files and I'm running Snow Leopard.

Comment: There was no Word 2007 for Mac to my knowledge. I've replaced the references with 2008 instead, but if you're using the 2011 version you can edit the question accordingly.